# compiler warning on setting 32nd bit

Tags: c, 32-bit, keil

I have compiler warning in code while setting 32nd bit. Code works but this warning annoys me.

Compiler is Keil C, processor is 32 bit ARM. Code is as following

```
PINSEL0 |= PINSEL_AD15;
```

where `PINSEL0` is 32 bit register, defined as

```
#define PINSEL0         (*((volatile unsigned long *) 0xE002C000))
```

and `PINSEL_AD15` is defined like:

```
#define PINSEL_AD15  ((1<<30)|(1<<31))
```

The warning message I'm receiving is: *integer operation result is out of range*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The literal `1` is a *signed* integer, so when you shift by 31, you're going out of range.  Try using an unsigned integer:

```
(1U << 31)
```